# Select from table with object_id

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Is is it possible to select Data like this in SQL Server?

```
select * 
from table(object_id)
```

I would like so pass the object_id as parameter to the select because I need to select from a global temptable which looks different and has a different name every time. The object_id I get like this:

```
select object_id('tempdb..##temptableXXX')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No. Or only by getting the name corresponding to the object id and using dynamic SQL. Which makes the roundtrip through object id pointless.

Answer (score 5):

You could do that with a little bit of T-SQL:

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(max)
select @tablename = name from sys.tables
where object_id = select object_id('tempdb..##temptableXXX')

declare @sql nvarchar(max) =
'select * from ' + @tablename
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: The way with T-SQL i know. But i need the date in a local temptable to do some more manipulation with them. I know how i can get data from exec to a temptable. But this temptable must be created before the exec. But the structure of the global temptable is different every time so i cant create the local temptable in advance.

Thanks for your try.

Comment: @Joni. This answers the question you asked. If it is not what you need, then you should probably have asked a different or more precise question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following, even though the answer looks a lot like what has already been provided. However this allows you to add more than just tables in the i.e. table valued functions views etc.

It also takes into account that the object is not in calling user's default schema and uses two-part name in the from clause i.e. `[Schema].[Table]`

Also it protects you against SQL-Injection attacks, using `QUOTENAME()` function.

```
/* input param*/
Declare @object_id  INT = 117575457;


Declare @SchemaName SYSNAME 
      , @TableName  SYSNAME
      , @Sql        NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @TableName  = [name] 
      , @SchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME([SCHEMA_ID]) 
from    sys.objects
WHERE   [type_desc] = 'USER_TABLE'  --<- Can use IN Clause to add functions veiws etc
  AND   [object_id] = @object_id;   --<-- User Input variable

 SET @sql = N' SELECT * FROM ' 
          + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName); 

 Exec sp_executesql @sql;
```